# Multiple dropdownlist postback in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code on a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <div class="select-box form">
        <p>
            <strong>Select transcript name to view:</strong>
            @Html.DropDownList("license", (SelectList)ViewBag.Licenses, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="select-box form">
        <p>
            <strong>You may have multiple periods for each transcript name:</strong>
            @Html.DropDownList("period", (SelectList)ViewBag.Periods, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

I need to implement some logic depending on which dropdown cause the postback. I'm thinking to add a hidden input and set value of the control name by jQuery before submit the form, but I'm wondering if there is a 'native' way to do this.

This is my controller signature:

```
public ActionResult Checklist(int license, int period)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using javascript is offcourse a solution , but also think for scenario's with javascript disabled. Your app must degrade gracefully on javascript disabled clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply a class to the dropdown so that my jQuery can use that as the selector criteria

```
 @Html.DropDownList("license", (SelectList)ViewBag.Licenses, new { @class="mySelect"})
 @Html.DropDownList("period", (SelectList)ViewBag.Periods, new { @class="mySelect"})
 <input type="hidden" id="source" name="source" value="" />
```

And the script is

```
$(function(){

 $(".mySelect").change(function(){
   var itemName=$(this).attr("name");
   $("#source").val(itemName);
    $("form").submit()
 });

});
```

Comment: Yap, I'm doing something very similar. Take a look to my edit. But what I wanted to know if there was another way. Out of curiosity, this work perfect and is not hard to implement. Thanks by the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this. (Here you are calling the action method instead of submitting the form)

Which ever dropdown caused the change will pass non zero value to the action method and the other will pass 0.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("license", (SelectList)ViewBag.Licenses, new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/ControllerName/Checklist?license=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + '&period=0'" })
 @Html.DropDownList("period", (SelectList)ViewBag.Periods, new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/ControllerName/Checklist?license=0&period=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

Hope this helps!